# Find non-UTF-8 data in mysql

Tags: mysql, encoding

I have a MySQL database containing data that is input by our customers.

Customers are told their data should only be encoded as UTF-8, however this is currently not being enforced and some people are using characters not encoded in UTF-8.

We intend to add some checking, however how should we detect data that isn't encoded using UTF-8?  Is there a SQL or MySQL query (or admin command) that will show me the data that is NOT encoded as UTF-8?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can check for the existence of (non-)UTF-8 data by comparing byte length to character length on a column, e.g.:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable
WHERE LENGTH(MyColumn) <> CHAR_LENGTH(MyColumn)
```

Multibyte characters will have a greater `LENGTH` (bytes), so you'll need to look for where that condition isn't met.

Note that MySQL's `utf8` character set isn't true Unicode UTF-8 as it only supports a maximum of 3 bytes per character. If your MySQL is later than 5.5.3 you can use `utf8mb4` to get 4 bytes per character.

Comment: So in my case using SELECT * FROM TABLE where length(COLUMN) > char_length(COLUMN) worked a treat and returned the entries that had none utf8.

Comment: I don't think this is right. UTF-8 can encode characters in 1 to 4 bytes, so how does comparing character length to byte length reveal non-UTF-8 data? One byte per character only contains (roughly) ASCII characters, so the question that you're answering here is how to find non ASCII chars, not non-UTF-8 chars. Am I missing something?

Comment: This is incorrect -- it will flag any text with non-ASCII characters. Valid UTF8, but not ASCII -- just as @goron warned in 2016.

Comment: so, to expound upon this answer being incorrect, how would `LENGTH('this is a test') <> CHAR_LENGTH('this is a test')` be discovered as *not* being encoded in UTF-8?  That string has the same `LENGTH()` and `CHAR_LENGTH()`.   `CHAR_LENGTH()` returns the *number of characters in argument*, and `LENGTH()` returns *the length of a string in bytes*, which is the same for a string consisting of *only* ASCII-encoded characters.

Comment: @HannahVernon you are right but that's not the question. The OP wants to find if there are characters that are not in UTF-8. Plain ASCII characters are encoded similarly in, say, Latin-1 and UTF-8, but extended ASCII chars are encoded differently. E.g. á in Latin-1 is 0xE1, but in UTF-8 it's 0xC3A1 -- different length.

Comment: @mustaccio but the question isn't about "extended ASCII chars", just if it's encoded using UTF-8

Comment: @mustaccio - yes, except the answer will only return rows where the length and char_length are *different*, but the OP wants to return rows that are encoded in ASCII.  `this` is certainly encoded in ASCII, and has the same `length` and `char_length`, unless I'm misunderstanding.

Comment: For plain ASCII any encoding equals that of UTF-8, for anything else the length will be different. If a column value contains only plain ASCII chars that's the same as UTF-8. `this` is represented in Latin-1 and UTF-8 with the same byte sequence. `thát` is not, which is exactly the problem the OP wants to solve. "not encoded in UTF-8" is not the same question as "encoded in ASCII".

Answer (score 0):

This will only select fields which are not valid UTF-8:

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE CONVERT(field USING binary) RLIKE '([\\xC0-\\xC1]|[\\xF5-\\xFF]|\\xE0[\\x80-\\x9F]|\\xF0[\\x80-\\x8F]|[\\xC2-\\xDF](?![\\x80-\\xBF])|[\\xE0-\\xEF](?![\\x80-\\xBF]{2})|[\\xF0-\\xF4](?![\\x80-\\xBF]{3})|(?<=[\\x00-\\x7F\\xF5-\\xFF])[\\x80-\\xBF]|(?<![\\xC2-\\xDF]|[\\xE0-\\xEF]|[\\xE0-\\xEF][\\x80-\\xBF]|[\\xF0-\\xF4]|[\\xF0-\\xF4][\\x80-\\xBF]|[\\xF0-\\xF4][\\x80-\\xBF]{2})[\\x80-\\xBF]|(?<=[\\xE0-\\xEF])[\\x80-\\xBF](?![\\x80-\\xBF])|(?<=[\\xF0-\\xF4])[\\x80-\\xBF](?![\\x80-\\xBF]{2})|(?<=[\\xF0-\\xF4][\\x80-\\xBF])[\\x80-\\xBF](?![\\x80-\\xBF]))';
```

(The regex is from https://stackoverflow.com/a/11709412/323407.
Requires PCRE regex support. MySQL does not have that out of the box but MariaDB 10.0.5+ does. For MySQL maybe you can use [lib_mysqludf_preg](https://github.com/mysqludf/lib_mysqludf_preg).)

Not sure if this is what the question is asking for - if someone stored their information in an encoding that is not UTF-8 but happens to output byte sequences that are valid UTF-8, this will not help with that (and I don't think a 100% reliable solution exists - if you know the specific encoding and language, you can maybe look for common corrupted character sequences). But it's useful for finding input that's definitely not UTF-8.

(This assumes the text is stored in a format where invalid UTF-8 is even possible, e.g. binary.)